# How to display a pe:timeline in a vertical position

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timeline/editClient.jsf

Please refer the link. In the link timeline is displayed in a horizontal way. Is there any possibility to display it vertically?

Comment: You should provide the code of what you tried so far

Comment: i have no idea about primefaces.. and tring it for the first time.. i have tried the code which is present in the link.. but that displayes horizotal timeline..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no this is not possible.

See also http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17418

Make google your friend